# Why classes that implement variant interfaces remain invariant?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ienumerable, covariance

C# 4.0 has extended the co and contravariance further for generic types and interfaces. Some interfaces (like `IEnumerable<T>`) are covariants, so I can do things like:

```
IEnumerable<object> ie = new List<string>();
```

but what about this line? I got a compile-time error

```
List<Object> list = new List<String>();
//Cannot implicitly convert type List<string>' to List<object>'
```

I mean, if `List<T>` implement `IEnumerable<T>` why `List<T>` is still invariant? Is out there a good counterexample that explain why this should not be allowed in C#?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Firstly, classes are *always* invariant in C#. You can't declare a class like this:

```
// Invalid
public class Foo<out T>
```

Secondly - and more importantly for the example you've given - `List<T>` couldn't be declared to be covariant or contravariant in `T` anyway, as it has members both accepting and returning values of type `T`.

Imagine if it *were* covariant. Then you could write this (for the obvious `Fruit` class hierarchy):

```
List<Banana> bunchOfBananas = new List<Banana>();
// This would be valid if List<T> were covariant in T
List<Fruit> fruitBowl = bunchOfBananas;
fruitBowl.Add(new Apple());
Banana banana = bunchOfBananas[0];
```

What would you expect that last line to do? Fundamentally, you shouldn't be able to add an `Apple` reference to an object whose actual execution-time type is `List<Banana>`. If you add an apple to a bunch of bananas, it falls off. Believe me, I've tried.

The last line *should* be safe in terms of types - the only values within a `List<Banana>` should be `null` or references to instances of `Banana` or a subclass.

Now as for why classes can't be covariant even when they could *logically* be... I believe that introduces problems at the implementation level, and would also be *very* restrictive at the programming level as well. For example, consider this:

```
public class Foo<out T> // Imagine if this were valid
{
    private T value;

    public T Value { get { return value; } }

    public Foo(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

That would still probably have to be invalid - the variable is still writable, meaning it counts as an "in" slot. You'd have to make every variable of type `T` read-only... and that's just for starters. I strongly suspect that there would be deeper problems.

In terms of pure pragmatism, the CLR has supported delegate and interface variance from v2 - C# 4 just introduced the syntax to expose the feature. I don't believe the CLR has ever supported generic class variance.

Comment: Jon, how does this account for having a list of Fruit that you would add instances of class that inherit from Fruit? For example, `List<Fruit> fruitBowl = new List<Fruit>(); fruitBowl.Add(new Apple()); fruitBowl.add(new Banana());` I've done this in the past and it always behaves as expected. Why doesn't the CLR look at the type of `fruitBowl`? Is it because you are setting the value of your `fruitBowl` to a list of Bananas first which is covariant to a list of `Fruit` and *then* trying to add an invariant `Apple` to that same collection?

Comment: @elucid8: It's absolutely fine to have a `List<Fruit>` and add arbitrary fruit to it. It's just not correct to say that a `List<Banana>` is a `List<Fruit>` - precisely *because* you can't add arbitrary fruit to a `List<Banana>`. I'm not sure I understand your question. Perhaps ask in a new post, if this doesn't help? (Comment threads aren't ideal for this.)

Comment: I don't agree with Jon, I think he is mistaken in what if we are discussing COVARIANCE then we have to use a method of the LIST what returns T. But Jon is about method ADD which ACCEPTS T so we need to talk about CONTRAVARIANCE and in this case all things will go in right way

Comment: So then you think it's impossible to ever get a value out of a list?  That's...not the case.

Comment: Servy, yes. But we are discussing here not collections, but CLASS VARIANCE!

Comment: @MaximQ: And the problem is precisely because there *is* an `Add` method, accepting values into it. We're discussing covariance because the OP wants to be able to assign a value of type `List<string>` to a variable of type `List<object>`. That could only work if `List<T>` were covariant in `T`. But it can't logically be covariant in `T` because the `Add` method (and similar methods accepting a `T`) exist.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to discuss adding (accepting) something (T) to List, we must talk about CONTRAVARIANCE (COVARIANCE doesn't allow accepting), so:

```
List<Fruit> bunchOfFruits = new List<Fruit>();
// This would be valid if List<T> were contravariant in T
List<Banana> bunchOfBananas = bunchOfFruits;
bunchOfBananas.Add(new Apple()); // not possible! We have compile error, coz in spite of Apple is a Fruit it is not ancestor of Banana. No logical mistakes.
bunchOfBananas.Add(new BigBanana()); // possible coz of rules of C#! we deal with a descendant of Banana
bunchOfBananas.Add(new Fruit()); // possible, coz CONTRAVARIANCE of List. We deal with the ancestor of Banana. No logical mistakes.
```

So as we can see VARIANCE should work either for classes too as for interfaces and delegates (classes in general, not only for collections). And I think it can be implemented in future versions of .NET.