# Dynamic instance of c# list with inherited type

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, dynamic, polymorphism

**Case 1:**
I have the following case: I want to apply dynamic polymorphism to a List.

I have a base class ALayer

```
public class ALayer {
   int Id {get; set;}
}
```

And another base class A that contains a list of layers

```
public class A {
   List<ALayer> Layers {get; set;}
}
```

Then I will have several classes that extends from my base classes:

```
public class BLayer: Alayer {
   int blayerattr {get; set;}
}

public class B:A {
   //I want to apply the polymorphism in the constructor
   public B(){
     this.Layers = new List<BLayer>();//error
   }
}

public class CLayer: Alayer {
   int clayerattr {get; set;}
}

public class C:A {
   //I want to apply the polymorphism in the constructor
   public C(){
      this.Layers = new List<CLayer>();//error
   }

}
```

but the compiler gives me an error of not being able to implicitly cast the Child Layer into the Parent Layer. The child layers are quite different so I decided to create the ALayer Parent Class.

is it possible to code this? or do I have a flaw in my design? or how do I instance my list depending on the type of class?

Thank you in advance!

## **Edited Question**

**Case 2:**
Following the last case, how do I apply this Generics to a middle class in the inheritance? let's say there exists a Middle class between A and B

```
public class Middle:A{
   int   anyatrr;
}
```

and then my class B inherits from Middle, but still in the B constructor is where I want to apply the dynamic polymorphism.

```
public class B:Middle {       
   public B(){
     this.Layers = new List<BLayer>();
   }
}
```

How can I combine in the Middle class the Generics notation plus the inheritance from the class A

Comment: Is it me or you do the exact same thing with your 'B' and 'C' stuffs. Then, to make your question more clear, you should remove the 'C' cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Generics:

```
public abstract class ALayer
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class A<T> where T : ALayer
{
    protected List<T> Layers { get; set; }
}

public class B : A<BLayer>
{
    //I want to apply the polymorphism in the constructor
    public B()
    {
        this.Layers = new List<BLayer>();
    }
}

public class BLayer : ALayer
{
    int blayerattr { get; set; }
}
```

You can get a lot more information on C# generics here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx

**Update**

Case 2
(Credits to X.L.Ant)

Just do :

```
public class Middle<T> : A<T>{ and then public class B : Middle<BLayer> {
```

Comment: The answer's correct. Would be even more helpful if you explained a bit the generics invariance.

Comment: Also you can add `class A : A<ALayer>` :o)

Comment: This talks a bit about [invariance and covariance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13107168/1679537)

Comment: @X.L.Ant, thank you, your answer was correct, but I have a different case now, please see my edited question.

Comment: Just do : `public class Middle<T> : A<T>{` and then `public class B : Middle<BLayer> {`

Comment: Sorry, the original thanks was for @EduardoBrites for the quick answer, please see my edited question, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guessed that. My comment seems valid anyway :)

Comment: @X.L.Ant,@EduardoBrites  I'm getting this error
The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method '... There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T'     =(

Comment: That's getting confusing. Please either edit your question, or better, accept @EduardoBrites answer and ask a new one. The comments are not the place for that.