# Casting ICollection of a concrete type to an ICollection of the concrete type interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, icollection

What is the recommended way to cast an `ICollection<Bar>` to `ICollection<IBar>` where `Bar` implements `IBar`?

Is it as simple as

```
collection = new List<Bar>();
ICollection<IBar> = collection as ICollection<IBar>?
```

or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: It's not quite an exact duplicate, but read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107071 to see why your solution won't work. (It has syntax errors already, but even if it didn't, it would give `null` as a result of the `as` operator.)

Comment: You cannot cast to `ICollection<IBar>`, but you can cast to `IEnumerable<IBar>`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, thank you. I see now that none of the other answers mention this possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to cast every item in the list and create a new one, for example with [`Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb341406(v=vs.95).aspx):

```
ICollection<IBar> ibarColl = collection.Cast<IBar>().ToList();
```

In .NET 4, using the covariance of `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
ICollection<IBar> ibarColl = collection.ToList<IBar>();
```

or with [`List.ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ICollection<IBar> ibarColl = collection.ConvertAll(b => (IBar)b);
```

The latter might be a little bit more efficient since it knows the size beforehand.

Comment: That would create a copy of the original list. Is there a way to reuse the same `ICollection<T>` instance to add items and manipulate the collection?

Comment: @Shimmy only if it's an instance of IList<T> like an array or list. Then you can use a for loop and replace them or use Array.ConvertAll or list.ConvertAll as shown in the answer

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast to `ICollection<IBar>`, but you can cast to `IEnumerable<IBar>`.

So if you don't intend to add something to the list, you can do this:

`IEnumerable<IBar> enumeration = (IEnumerable<IBar>)collection;`

The solutions from the other answers don't actually cast but create a new list that will not reflect subsequent changes to the original list.

Answer (score 0):

Just convert all entries with

```
ICollection<IBar> ibars = collection.ConvertAll(bar => (IBar)bar);
```

I think this variant is also readable. Perhaps there are ways to cast it with more performance...