# Restrict passing instances of derived classes as method parameters

Tags: c#, .net

Here's the situation. I have a class and a derived class

```
public class MyClass
{  }

public class MyDerivedClass : MyClass
{  }
```

And also I have a method (in an external class) which takes an instance of `MyClass` as a parameter:

```
public class AnotherClass {
  public void DoSomething(MyClass myClass) 
  { }
}
```

How can I restrict `DoSomething` method to accept instances of `MyClass` only, but not instances of `MyDerivedClass`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You can't. You can check the type at runtime and throw an exception, but nothing the compiler can prevent

Comment: What you ask for is against object oriented programming, ***MyDerivedClass** IS **MyClass***. It's the same as "I don't want a car, but I want a Ferrari!"

Comment: @Esko,thank you. this is a useful remark for me because I wasn't sure if I was doing the right thing. My problem is simple: I have a class and a derived class which both share the same functionality but instances of those classes are stored in different databases and I would like to have different methods for manipulating content there instead of choosing proper database depending on the type of instance of a class

Comment: @Esko Your analogy is reversed.  It's like saying, "I'll accept any kind of car that exists, but I don't accept Ferraris."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's what you want then you would need to check in code yourself that if it is a **Derived** type through **Exception** to tell the calling code that **Derived** type objects are not allowed for this method:

```
public class AnotherClass {
  public void DoSomething(MyClass myClass) 
  { 
       if(myClass.GetType() != typeof(MyClass))
       {
          throw new Exception("Derived objects not allowed");
       }
  }
}
```

Comment: While I wouldn't recommend what OP wants (for the same reason as the comments on the question), this is the correct approach to satisfy the OPs (uncommon) request.

Comment: should I mark this answer as the correct one if this is considered as not recommended practice?

Comment: @AntonVoronin if it is answering the asked question and the answer solves that particular problem, then there is no harm in accepting it :)

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do here is more related to an Invariance problem that is pretty common on all programming languages.

> Means that you can use only the type originally specified; so an
>   invariant generic type parameter is neither covariant nor
>   contravariant. You cannot assign an instance of IEnumerable
>   (IEnumerable) to a variable of type
>   IEnumerable or vice versa.

Here is the reference for you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

My advice, try to change the implementation and put all the methods into an interface, that should be more clear

```
class Root: Interface
{
 ...implementation of your common methods
}

class Derived: Interface
{
  ...implementation of your common methods
  //this should just
  public void DoSomething(MyClass myClass)
}
```

If you don't want to use the above approach then use the "as" operator to treat the parameter that you are passing as MyRootClass, `var a = parameter as MyRootClass`. If a is *null* then you are not passing the correct value to the method, or check for the type directly.

If would recommend that you read this topics:

http://amapplease.blogspot.com/2009/04/invariance-covariance-contravariance.html
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13107168/819153
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity/

Hope this helps