# Defining/raising a generic event using constraints

Tags: c#, generics

I want to raise an event that will allow an object of type `Widget` (or any derived class) to be returned, with the specific type being defined via generics.

```
public class WidgetProcessor
{
   public event EventHandler<WidgetRequiredEventArgs<Widget>> WidgetRequired;

   public void DoSomethingThatNeedsAWidget<T>() where T: Widget
   {
      Widget widget = OnWidgetRequired<T>();

      //...now do something with the widget
   }

   private T OnWidgetRequired<T>() where T: Widget
   {
      T widget = null;

      if (this.WidgetRequired != null)
      {
         WidgetRequiredEventArgs<T> e = new WidgetRequiredEventArgs<T>();
         this.WidgetRequired(this, e);

         widget = e.Widget;
      }

      return widget;
   }
}

public class WidgetRequiredEventArgs<T>
   : EventArgs where T : Widget
{
   public WidgetRequiredEventArgs()
   {
   }

   public T Widget { get; set; }
}
```

Constraints on `OnWidgetRequired<T>()` and `DoSomethingThatNeedsAWidget<T>()` allow me to limit the specified type to `Widget` or a derived class.  Ideally, I'd do the same for the event declaration, but it doesn't support the use of `<T>` with a constraint for the event args, so I've had to declare it explicitly as `Widget`.

However, this gives the compile-time error:

> CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'WidgetRequiredEventArgs<T>' to 'WidgetRequiredEventArgs<Widget>'

for the `e` argument on the line:

```
this.WidgetRequired(this, e);
```

So why don't the constraints on `OnWidgetRequired<T>()` and `WidgetRequiredEventArgs<T>` satisfy the eventhandler's type definition, and how can I get it to compile?

Comment: What you're trying to do is illegal, because it's unsafe. Your proposed syntax would allow any subscriber that can produce any kind of `Widget` to handle the production of a `Widget` for any arbitrary type of `Widget`. I.e. the subscriber could produce a `WidgetA` even when the caller of `OnWidgetRequired<T>()` is called for a `WidgetB`. If you can adjust the question to describe an operation that isn't illegal, then maybe a good answer can be provided. Otherwise, it's just a duplicate of all the other "my desired variant type scenario is illegal" questions we already have.

Comment: What is actual purpose of `WidgetRequired`? What should happen if there are multiple subscribers to this event?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Looks you're right that this is 'just a duplicate of all the other "my desired variant type scenario is illegal" questions we already have', but none of the others explained clearly enough why my scenario was illegal, hence my question.

Comment: @GuruStron The code is in a UI library and event is really just to allow it to request an object without any knowledge/dependence of where it's coming from.  So in practice, there's only ever one subscriber representing the UI environment that is using this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fundamental problem in your example. You want for subscribers to the event to be able to produce the object type that you specify in your generic method. I.e. your method creates the args object, the handler *sets* the property, the method raises the property, and then the method *gets* the property value.

But if you could do what you're asking, then producers could set whatever type of `Widget` they are designed to handle, even if it's not the type of `Widget` that the method was being called to retrieve.

Or put another way, the property's generic type cannot be variant, because it's legal to only be covariant or contravariant, not both at the same time.

One approach would be to move the event itself into a generic type, rather than using a generic method. This allows the event to be declared using the correct type at every step of the way. The framework will instantiate a new concrete type, with a separate event, for each generic type parameter used in the code.

For example, here's a simple generic implementation (I've renamed the class names from `Widget` to something more readable, so it's more clear the relationship between types, and I've made everything `static` for simplicity...of course, you could make these non-static if you had a scenario where it made sense to have more than one event using the same generic type parameter):

```cs
class Base { }
class Derived1 : Base { }
class Derived2 : Base { }

class BaseEventArgs<T> : EventArgs where T : Base
{
    public T Item { get; set; }
}

static class ItemHandler<T> where T : Base
{
    public static event EventHandler<BaseEventArgs<T>> ItemProducer;

    public static T OnBaseRequired()
    {
        BaseEventArgs<T> args = new BaseEventArgs<T>();

        ItemProducer?.Invoke(null, args);

        return args.Item;
    }
}
```

Then you just use it something like this:

```cs
public void DoSomethingThatNeedsABase<T>() where T : Base
{
    Base widget = ItemHandler<T>.OnBaseRequired();

    //...now do something with the "Base", aka "widget
}
```

Comment: So to really simplify the answer, T might be specified as Derived1 but because the eventhandler accepts any type of Base, someone could pass in a Derived2 instead.  Aaagh, so obvious once you describe it like that.

Answer (score 2):

Classes in C# does not allow variance ([and for good reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13107168/2501279)). You can try introducing an [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/creating-variant-generic-interfaces) interface for you event args if that will suit your use case:

```
public interface  IWidgetRequiredEventArgs<out T> where T : Widget
{
   public T Widget { get; }
}

public class WidgetRequiredEventArgs<T>
   : EventArgs, IWidgetRequiredEventArgs<T> where T : Widget
{
   public WidgetRequiredEventArgs()
   {
   }

   public T Widget { get; set; }
}
```

And use it for event handler:

```
public event EventHandler<IWidgetRequiredEventArgs<Widget>> WidgetRequired;
```

Or you can make the `WidgetProcessor` generic:

```
public class WidgetProcessor<T> where T: Widget
{
   public event EventHandler<WidgetRequiredEventArgs<T>> WidgetRequired;

   public void DoSomethingThatNeedsAWidget() 
   {
      Widget widget = OnWidgetRequired();

      //...now do something with the widget
   }

   private T OnWidgetRequired()
   {
       ....
   }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because as you can see in the original code, the property is set by the event handler, and retrieved by the code that raises the event. The type parameter cannot be covariant and contravariant at the same time, but that would be necessary in order to implement the logic in the original question. You've answered a _different question_. Though now that I think about it...maybe if you change the interface so that it's contravariant instead of covariant.

Comment: @PeterDuniho event handler (i.e. OnWidgetRequired) still creates a concrete type, so it can set it, no changes needed there. This pretty much compiles.

Comment: It needs to compile in an identical context to the original question. I.e. show not just the declarations above, but also the event, a subscriber, and the code that raises the event, all working in concert. Pay very close attention to the fact that in the OP's code, the handler is _setting_ the event args property.

Comment: @PeterDuniho there is no actual handlers in the code, but yes, it looks like it is the goal.

Comment: _"maybe if you change the interface so that it's contravariant instead of covariant."_ -- oh, and I was wrong about that...that just moves the problem to the invocation of the handler. Still doesn't work, and for good reason