# Why does the compiler only allow a generic returned task if I `async`/`await` it?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, generics, async-await

I'm trying to return a specifically typed value from a generic function (`GenericGetter`).

When I try to simply return the typed `Task` result from `GenericGetter`, the compiler is showing me the following error:

```
Cannot convert expression type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Example.ChildClass>' 
    to return type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Example.BaseClass>'
```

However, if I make the function that contains the `GenericGetter` call `async`, and I return the awaited value instead, the compiler doesn't mind. It compiles, it works, but to me it seems the added async / await are redundant.

#### Why does `GetChildClass` not compile, while `GetChildClassAsync` *does*?

Here's my example:

```
namespace Example
{
    public class BaseClass {}
    public class ChildClass : BaseClass {}

    public class MyExample
    {
        private async Task Main()
        {
            var foo = await GetChildClass().ConfigureAwait(false);
            var bar = await GetChildClassAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private Task<BaseClass> GetChildClass() =>
            GenericGetter<ChildClass>();

        private async Task<BaseClass> GetChildClassAsync() =>
            await GenericGetter<ChildClass>().ConfigureAwait(false);

        private Task<T> GenericGetter<T>()
            where T : BaseClass =>
            Task.FromResult<T>(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is either covariance or contravariance

Comment: `Task<T>` isn't covariant

Comment: May also be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30996986/why-is-taskt-not-co-variant

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting List<> of Derived class to List<> of base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720751/casting-list-of-derived-class-to-list-of-base-class) Essentially the same problem: lack of variance

Comment: @Charlieface no, if anything, DavidG's link is a more suitable duplicate. The whole _"Add a Dog to a list of what used to be cats"_ example isn't relevant here, as we're not talking lists with possible assignment.

Comment: A class cannot be co- or contra-variant according to the CLR and C# rules, so yes it's the same thing. Theoretically it could have been implemented using interfaces, at significant extra complexity. See also this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/13107168/14868997. You have to remember that if you could in theory create a clss `Task<out T>` then that class could not have a `T field;` because it would be writable. Even `readonly` won't help. So that removes the whole point of such a class: to be able to store the result of the task.

Comment: @Charlieface All I'm saying is that the dupe target you proposed is very focused on `List` functionality, which isn't relevant to this question at all. David's link is much more to the point.

Comment: @DavidG Perhaps vote to close as dupe using your link?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `GetChildClass`, you're trying to convert a `Task<ChildClass>` into `Task<BaseClass>` - that doesn't work, because `Task<T>` is *invariant* (as are all classes; only interfaces and delegates can be generically covariant or contravariant - all arrays support covariance, although in an "interesting" way).

In `GetChildClassAsync`, you're trying to convert a `ChildClass` into a `BaseClass` (which is allowed by normal inheritance and conversions) - and the C# compiler then does the wrapping into a `Task<BaseClass>`, so that's fine.

I see why it appears to be redundant, and there are *potentially* more efficient ways that it could be done (it would be nice to be able to create a `Task<SomeBaseType>` from `Task<SomeChildType>` using a framework method/constructor) but I'd suggest just living with it.

Comment: So, it's a deliberate restriction / design choice on `Task`. At least that means I'm not entirely crazy :D Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Cerbrus No, all classes in C# are invariant. The compiler _implicitly_ returns a `Task<BaseClass>` when you use `async`, but it's `Result` can reference the returned `ChildClass`.

Comment: @Cerbrus Well, all classes are invariant so not really deliberate with respect to `Task<T>`

Comment: Okay, so if I understand correctly it's the inheritance and conversion from `Task<Child>` to `Task<Base>` that would require a manual implementation? _"Just living with it"_ then seems like a more efficient choice.

Comment: Don't forget arrays can be covariant too e.g. `BaseClass[] items = new ChildClass[5];`

Comment: @Cerbrus [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530099/how-to-convert-a-tasktderived-to-a-tasktbase).

Comment: @DavidG: Have added a note. Array variance is weird and annoying IMO :)